# Render child component to get its html in vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-test-utils

I have one Parent Component called SuggestiveInput and it has Child Component called VueSimpleSuggest. I am getting stub of child component on the test instead of its content.

So SuggestiveInput component is like:

```
<template >
  <div class="suggestive-input">
    <vue-simple-suggest ...>
    </vue-simple-suggest>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueSimpleSuggest from "vue-simple-suggest";
import "vue-simple-suggest/dist/styles.css";

export default {
  name: "suggestive-input",

  props: {
    ...
  },

  components: {
    VueSimpleSuggest
  },
...
```

and my test file:

```
import chai from "chai";
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import SuggestiveInput from "@/components/input/SuggestiveInput";
import * as VueTestUtils from "@vue/test-utils";

const expect = chai.expect;

describe("SuggestiveInput", function() {
  let wrapper;
  const localVue = createLocalVue();

  beforeEach(function() {
    wrapper = shallowMount(SuggestiveInput, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        suggestionList: ["Client One", "Client Two"],
        value: ""
      }
    });
  });

  it("shows input element with Bootstrap style", function() {
    expect(wrapper.html()).contains("input.form-control").to.be.true;
  });
});
```

**@vue/test-utils** version **^1.0.0-beta.20**

**vue** version **^2.5.19**

I am getting the following output:

```
 AssertionError: expected '<div data-v-6aad8d64="" class="suggestive-input"><vue-simple-suggest-stub data-v-6aad8d64=""></vue-simple-suggest-stub></div>' to include 'input.form-control'
```

It renders the stub of the child component. How can I render the child component to get pure HTML of the parent component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried both `mount()` and `shallowMount()` but didn't get what I wanted. I used the `render()` method which uses `vue-server-renderer` under the hood to render a component to static HTML. `render` is included in the `@vue/server-test-utils` package. The documentation could be found [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/render.html).

Another approach is to use `shallowMount` but in the test, access the child component using `wrapper.find(ChildComponent)`.

I tried both methods and they worked properly.

Comment: have you got the full code? Having similar issues and can't see ChildComponent in your code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To get the content of child components, you need to use `mount()`, not `shallowMount()`.

From the Vue Test Utils docs:

- [mount()](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount): "Creates a `Wrapper` that contains the mounted and rendered Vue component."
- [shallowMount()](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#shallowmount): "Like `mount`, it creates a `Wrapper` that contains the mounted and rendered Vue component, but **with stubbed child components**."

Answer (score 0):

Since Vue Test Utils for vue3 took out `render()`, I find this in their document which allows you to register any child component globally [source](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-components)

No need to await for `$nextTick() or` $forceUpdate()`, like below:

```
describe("SuggestiveInput", function() {
  let wrapper;
  const localVue = createLocalVue();

  beforeEach(function() {
    wrapper = shallowMount(SuggestiveInput, {
      localVue,
      globals: {
          components: { VueSimpleSuggest }
      }
    });
  });

  it("shows input element with Bootstrap style", function() {
    expect(wrapper.html()).contains("input.form-control").to.be.true;
  });
});
```